# Website showing x amount of answers while there are none if deleted before answer was loaded in

Tags: bug

If an answer is given while you are looking at a question, it shows "x new answer(s)" or something similar. If you click this after the answer was already deleted, it shows that the question has an answer while it doesn't. A page refresh solves the issue.

It's a very minor bug but I thought I'd mention it.

[image: example showing 1 answer while there are none]

Comment: The answer is actually there, when you reach 10k of rep, you can see deleted answers too.

Comment: Not sure how that can be changed. Someone published an answer -> others get notifed -> others click on the notification -> answers get loaded -> in the meantime answer got deleted ... No matter how that gets changed, there is always some point in time were your local verison is lacking behind

Comment: @JonasWilms Well the system notifies a user of new answers while looking at a question. I assumed the same could be done for deleted answers. Like _"2 new answer(s)"_ could simply be turned into _"1 new answer(s)"_ on deletion of an answer.

Comment: @Teemu True. I only mentioned it because I can imagine it'll be confusing for new users. Imagine you don't know what's going on here. You click the notification about new answer(s). It tells you there are x amount of answers. Yet you see none.

Comment: @JonasWilms I just thought of another solution that would be less heavy on SO's server resources: Use Javascript to count the amount of visible answers on clicking the notification. That way you don't have to push another notification to users on deletion. And I assume it'll be a lot easier than pushing "answer deleted" notifications to < 10k rep users, but not anyone above that rep.

Comment: @Teemu But the count doesn't normally consider deleted answers.

Comment: @JonasWilms Clicking the button to load new ones updates the count. The point is that it should update it to the correct count, even if the answers it tries to load are deleted after the pop up but before the load.